# Making a wysiwyg in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, wysiwyg

What I would like to do is to make a WYSIWYG editor, not a big one, just the common utilities, so bold, italic, underline, size, font, in Qt.

My approach for now is to make it in a QTextEdit, when the user click the button i get the signal and using the cursor index i put html tag, but I don't know if it's a good idea.

Any Advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always use the **webkit** module and relay on the `contentEditable` feature.

Comment: +1 for this. If I recall correctly, there's a nice demo based on this included in the Qt sources.

Comment: Not in the Qt sources, is in the experimental [graphics-dojo](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-labs/graphics-dojo/) repository. Here it is: [htmleditor](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-labs/graphics-dojo/trees/master/htmleditor)

Answer (score 2):

> Any Advice?

Study "Order form" and "Syntax Highlighter" examples. Also, read QTextCursor and QTextDocument documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I think you refer to the internal format of a document. You just need a solution to keep the formating information, so the editor/viewer can interpret it. Of cause you can choose HTML or HTML-like tags for this. I'd recommend to check out [BBCodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBCode), which are widely used for that.

By the nature of WYSIWYG the internal format should be invisible to a user. I don't know about the capabilities of QTextEdit to achieve that. Perhaps there is a HTML/BBCode extension?